# detect arguments from command line

Tags: c#

My required commandline is as follow:

`sortfolder.exe -6.70_Extensions -7`

where `7` is in `foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(7))`

and `-6.70_Extensions` is in `var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Work\\6.70_Extensions\\Build");` and `static string path = "C:\\Work\\6.70_Extensions\\Build\\"`

sortfolder.exe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace sortfolder
{
    class Program
    {
        static string path = "C:\\Work\\6.70_Extensions\\Build\\";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Work\\6.70_Extensions\\Build");

            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

            var files = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "SASE Lab Tools.*");
            foreach(var file in files)
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(7))
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip(7))
            Directory.Delete(file, true);
        }
    }
}
```

so my commandline is something of the form of:
`sortfolder.exe -version -integer`

and this `version` could be of any form:

```
6.70_Extensions
6.80_Extensions
7.00_Main
7.20_Main
8.00_Extensions
etc
```

and `integer`

can be any integer

how can i achieve this?

EDIT:

after browsing through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96s74eb0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

i edited my code:

```
namespace sortfolder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Work\\{0}\\Build", args[0]);
            string path = ("C:\\Work\\{0}\\Build\\", args[0]) ;
            foreach (var file in di.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                file.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

            var files = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "SASE Lab Tools.*");
            foreach(var file in files)
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip({0}), args[1])
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            foreach(var file in files.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Skip({0}), args[1])
            Directory.Delete(file, true);
        }
    }
}
```

something is not right in my syntax??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `string[] args` in `Main()`? Make use of it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

The above link has all the explanations and examples to get you going.

Comment: As a hint, args[0] will be `-6.70_Extensions`